# Why did they let the Shadow King go at the end of season 2 of Legion?

Tags: marvel, legion

At the end of season 2 of *Legion*, everyone turned on David Holler. They set the Shadow King free and tried to capture David, who then escapes.

Now, regardless of whether they should have captured David or not (and whether or not there is reason to believe they did so because of the Shadow King's influence), I can't fathom a reason for them to set the Shadow King free. Even if they suddenly esteem David very dangerous, it doesn't the Shadow King any less dangerous.

It seems to me (considering the last scene we see of the Shadow King in prison, where he finds a rat into whose ear he whispers) that the Shadow King found a way to influence his captors from within his prison, and then make them set him free. However, unless I missed something, this was never explicitly stated.

Is this what happened? Is there any "hard evidence" that it is?